# How to create a filppable stackview like LinkedIn

Tags: android

I have used the following link to create a filppable stack view https://github.com/blipinsk/FlippableStackView. But I want to create a flippable stack view like linkedin.. See the attachment.[image]. Can you guys help me?

Comment: [take a look](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266384/is-it-ok-to-downvote-questions-asking-about-how-to-achieve-something-without-ha)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The are plenty of libraries to implement animation like this. One of them https://github.com/kikoso/Swipeable-Cards which you can use easily with gradle. As alternative: https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards

Comment: Thank you so much rehman.. The first link is working fine.. But this works only for lollipop and marshmallow but not for lower versions.. Is there any alternative for lower versions like kitkat. And dependency from second link is not working..

Comment: Rehman: I imported code from https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards. This project works fine for kitkat also but the images are not coming in a stack.. i.e First image exactly overlaps the next image.

Comment: Yes, second library has problem as you mentioned. You can try these ones, i guess this one supports versions below marshmellow: https://github.com/wenchaojiang/AndroidSwipeableCardStack