# Vertical Stacked Views

Tags: android, flip, stackview, vertical-scroll

I'm struggling for the past 2 days to find/implement an working solution for my UI requirements for an on boarding flow. This is how the UI should look like:

[image: page #1] [image: page #2] 
[image: page #3] [image: page #4]

These pages should be scrollable **vertically only**.

As you can see, the pages should be stacked on top of each other. The current page (the top one) should also resize if not the first one so that the user can see the top edges of the already swiped up pages.

Beside the arrangement of the pages, when the user swipes an page up or down, there should also be an page transition, something similar to [DepthPageTransformer](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html), or at least to easily support changes for these transitions.

Until now I've tried:

- Custom vertical ViewPager
- Custom ScrollView with custom listener and one-by-one item scroll
- Flippable StackView (and multiple other implementations of StackView)

But I've failed to achieve the desired result using any of these approaches.

The flow is similar to the [linkedin flippable stackview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35081926/how-to-create-a-filppable-stackview-like-linkedin), with the difference that my requirements are for an vertical widget and with some small minor adjustments which can be adjusted afterwards.

Can someone please help me with this or at least guide me into the correct direction?

Thank you.

Comment: Hey, did you find any solution?

Comment: Hello, I ended up doing a lot of manual transformations via events passed by the current view that is moved. This is a little cumbersome and prone to errors, but it was enough for the feature I was implementing.

Comment: I managed in making this work with a ViewPager also preserving horizontal scroll behaviors. So I have a Vertical Stack Viewpager with doesn't block horizontal swipe, so it also would be possible to put this vertical ViewPager in a horizontal, that was my use case. I think I will write a Library for this, I will let you know, but it could take some time.

Comment: That sounds good, let me know when you have something implemented and best regards.

Comment: I managed to partially accomplish it using RecyclerView and using the whole screen as a single list entry and PageSnapHelper to treat every entry as a page. But I cannot get this visual effect(which I also need for my app) to work with that.Is it possible to do that with my implimentation.

Comment: @IonutNegru Can you post your code on github? Thanks